# How to parse com.google.cloud.retail.v2.Product object to JSON?

Tags: java, json, google-api, protobuf-c

I am implementing Google Retail Search into the project. Google API require me to provide [Product](https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.catalogs.branches.products#Product) object in given JSON format. JSON representation of Product with minimum number of fields populated look like following:

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "categories": "Apparel & Accessories > Shoes",
    "title": "ABC sneakers"
}
```

Corresponding Product object:

```
Product product = Product.newBuilder()
    .setId("1234")
    .addCategories("Apparel & Accessories > Shoes")
    .setTitle("ABC sneakers")
    .build();
```

When I try to parse the Product object to JSON using Gson library I receive following result:

```
{
    "expirationCase_": 0,
    "name_": "",
    "id_": "1234",
    "type_": 0,
    "primaryProductId_": "",
    "collectionMemberIds_": [],
    "gtin_": "",
    "categories_": [
      "Apparel & Accessories > Shoes"
    ],
    "title_": "ABC sneakers",
    "brands_": [],
    "description_": "",
    "languageCode_": "",
    "tags_": [],
    "availability_": 0,
    "fulfillmentInfo_": [],
    "uri_": "",
    "images_": [],
    "sizes_": [],
    "materials_": [],
    "patterns_": [],
    "conditions_": [],
    "promotions_": [],
    "variants_": [],
    "localInventories_": [],
    "memoizedIsInitialized": 1,
    "unknownFields": {
      "fields": {}
    },
    "memoizedSize": -1,
    "memoizedHashCode": 0
}
```

How can I parse com.google.cloud.retail.v2.Product objects to its correct JSON representation? Is there any Google provided solution or should I create my own Product?

I feel helpless on that.

I tried to use following Gson for parsing and have no idea what can I change here.

`Gson gson2 = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needed it, the solution is provide this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.22.2'
```

And parse product object to JSON with

```
com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat.printer().print(product);
```